# How to run stream to completion in Rust using combinators (other than for_each) and without a while loop?

Tags: rust

I have a stream which uses combinators and I need to run it to completion. I can use a `while` loop or the `for_each` combinator. They will both work, but I think there must be a nicer way.

[`Sink`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.6/futures/sink/trait.Sink.html) looks like what I'm looking for, especially [`sink::drain()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.6/futures/sink/fn.drain.html), but I havn't been able to understand how to use it.

Using while loop

```rust
use futures::{StreamExt, TryStreamExt}; // 0.3.6
use tokio; // 0.3.0

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut stream = Box::pin(
        futures::stream::iter(0..20)
            .map(foo)
            .map_ok(|x| x * 10)
            .and_then(bar)
            .filter(|x| futures::future::ready(x.is_ok())),
    );

    while let Some(_) = stream.next().await {
        // Nothing to do here. I just need to run stream.
    }
}

fn foo(x: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
    if x != 10 {
        Ok(x)
    } else {
        Err("eeer".to_string())
    }
}

async fn bar(x: i32) -> Result<(), String> {
    async {
        if x == 13 {
            Err("errr".to_string())
        } else {
            Ok(())
        }
    }
    .await
}
```

Using `for_each`:

```rust
use futures::{StreamExt, TryStreamExt}; // 0.3.6
use tokio; // 0.3.0

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    futures::stream::iter(0..20)
        .map(foo)
        .map_ok(|x| x * 10)
        .and_then(bar)
        .filter(|x| futures::future::ready(x.is_ok()))
        .for_each(|_| futures::future::ready(())) // Nothing to do here, just to run stream
        .await;
}

fn foo(x: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
    if x != 10 {
        Ok(x)
    } else {
        Err("eeer".to_string())
    }
}

async fn bar(x: i32) -> Result<(), String> {
    async {
        if x == 13 {
            Err("errr".to_string())
        } else {
            Ok(())
        }
    }
    .await
}
```

I would like to have something like the following. It's not necessary to use the `drain` combinator exactly, just some combinator to run the stream:

```rust
use futures::{StreamExt, TryStreamExt}; // 0.3.6
use tokio; // 0.3.0

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    futures::stream::iter(0..20)
        .map(foo)
        .map_ok(|x| x * 10)
        .and_then(bar)
        .filter(|x| futures::future::ready(x.is_ok()))
        .forward(futures::sink::drain())
        .await;
}

fn foo(x: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
    if x != 10 {
        Ok(x)
    } else {
        Err("eeer".to_string())
    }
}

async fn bar(x: i32) -> Result<(), String> {
    async {
        if x == 13 {
            Err("errr".to_string())
        } else {
            Ok(())
        }
    }
    .await
}
```

This doesn't work, probably because drain puts some bounds on the `Error` type:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<futures::sink::Drain<()> as futures::Sink<()>>::Error == std::string::String`
  --> src/main.rs:11:10
   |
11 |         .forward(futures::sink::drain())
   |          ^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::convert::Infallible`, found struct `std::string::String`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<futures::stream::Filter<futures::stream::AndThen<futures::stream::MapOk<futures::stream::Map<futures::stream::Iter<std::ops::Range<i32>>, fn(i32) -> std::result::Result<i32, std::string::String> {foo}>, [closure@src/main.rs:8:17: 8:27]>, impl futures::Future, fn(i32) -> impl futures::Future {bar}>, futures::future::Ready<bool>, [closure@src/main.rs:10:17: 10:54]> as futures::Stream>::Item == std::result::Result<(), std::convert::Infallible>`
  --> src/main.rs:6:5
   |
6  | /     futures::stream::iter(0..20)
7  | |         .map(foo)
8  | |         .map_ok(|x| x * 10)
9  | |         .and_then(bar)
10 | |         .filter(|x| futures::future::ready(x.is_ok()))
11 | |         .forward(futures::sink::drain())
12 | |         .await;
   | |______________^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found enum `std::convert::Infallible`
   |
   = note: expected enum `std::result::Result<_, std::string::String>`
              found enum `std::result::Result<_, std::convert::Infallible>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::Future` for `futures_util::stream::stream::forward::Forward<futures::stream::Filter<futures::stream::AndThen<futures::stream::MapOk<futures::stream::Map<futures::stream::Iter<std::ops::Range<i32>>, fn(i32) -> std::result::Result<i32, std::string::String> {foo}>, [closure@src/main.rs:8:17: 8:27]>, impl futures::Future, fn(i32) -> impl futures::Future {bar}>, futures::future::Ready<bool>, [closure@src/main.rs:10:17: 10:54]>, futures::sink::Drain<()>, ()>`
```

Comment: It's not clear why you dislike `.for_each` but like `forward`. What's the difference?

Comment: The difference is that it is more verbose and doesn't show my intentions well. My intention is to run stream or drain it if you will. For_each and while intention is do something with elements.

Answer (score 1):

`Sink` trait is fallible (there is no `TrySink`) but `drain()` returns a `Drain` whose `Error` is `Infallible`.

And `Stream::forward()` requires the stream to be fallible (actually `TryStream`) and have the same error type as the given sink. Your code fails because your error type is `String`, and that cannot be *drained*.

The solution, since you are filtering the `is_ok` results, it to unwrap and rewrap the values:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    futures::stream::iter(0..20)
        .map(foo)
        .map_ok(|x| x * 10)
        .and_then(bar)
        .filter(|x| futures::future::ready(x.is_ok()))
        .map(|x| Ok(x.unwrap())) // <---- rewrap!
        .forward(futures::sink::drain())
        .await.unwrap();
}
```

I feel that there should be an easier way to build a `Result<_, Infallible>`, but I don't know how. You could write `map_err(|_| panic!())` but that is hardly better.

Comment: `.filter_map(|x| async move { x.ok().map(Ok) })`

Comment: @Shepmaster: Ah, yes, that line would replace both the `filter` and the `map` calls, avoiding the need to call `unwrap()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collect::<()>()` to run the stream to completion. Example:

```
use futures::StreamExt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    futures::stream::iter(0..20)
        .map(|i| async move {
            // Do something here
            println!("{}", i);
        })
        .buffer_unordered(4)
        .collect::<()>()
        .await;
}
```

Although `collect::<()>()` has the word collect, it does not collect anything or build any data structure. It just loop over the stream and execute to completion.

One thing to note, to use `collect::<()>()` the `Item` of your stream must be `()`. In other words, you must handle both result and error before using this method. I think this make perfect sense.